# How to sign in Messages app in Mac Mavericks from terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, messages

Is it possible to sign in Message app from terminal ? When I search for it, I only see on how to send imessage from terminal. Thus, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

**Messages** supports [AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/Concepts/work_with_as.html). You can view the **Messages**'s AppleScript dictionary using the **AppleScript Editor**:

```
Applications > Utilities > AppleScript Editor.app
```

The AppleScript command `log in` suggests you can sign in programmatically:

> **log in** *v* : Log in to the specified service, or all services if none is specified. If the account password is not in the keychain the user will be prompted to enter one.

An example AppleScript to log in would be:

```
tell application "Messages"
    -- Log into every session
    log in
end tell
```

You can then use the [osascript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/osascript.1.html) command line tool to issue AppleScript commands via the **Terminal**:

An example `osascript` command to log in would be:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Messages" to log in'
```

Comment: Than you, Graham Miln. I will try it. I will confirm if it works soon.

Comment: Do you have any example code for log in ?

Comment: I can start with : using terms from application "Messages"

on login finished with eventDescription

end login finished

Comment: I have added examples for AppleScript and `osascript` approaches.

Comment: Thank again, Graham Miln. And can you tell me how I can put my apple ID and password to know it works well or not ?

Comment: I test the above codes in terminal, but nothing happens

Comment: I have no experience scripting Messages with AppleScript. You may be able to attract better answers with new specific AppleScript questions – or through an AppleScript specific forum.

Comment: yes, Graham Miln. I will go to that forum.